# Scrapy yield comma separated csv file

Tags: python, scrapy

I have made a program to extract materials online as follow. It works and do generate csv file. However, the data seems not to be comma separated as seen in excel file. **How can I fix that to make the file to be comma separated?**

```
import scrapy

class JPItem(scrapy.Item):
question_title = scrapy.Field() 
question_content = scrapy.Field()
question_link = scrapy.Field()
best_answer = scrapy.Field()
best_answer_link = scrapy.Field()

class JPSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = "jp"
allowed_domains = ['detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp']

start_urls = [
    'https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q' + str(x)
    for x in range (10000000000,100000000000)
]

def parse(self, response):
    item = JPItem()

    item['question_title'] = response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdQstn.sttsRslvd.clrfx div.ttl h1::text").extract_first()
    item['question_content'] = ''.join([i for i in response.css("div.mdPstdQstn div.ptsQes p::text").extract()])
    item['question_link'] = ''.join(response.css("div.mdPstdQstn p:not([class]) a::text").extract())
    item['best_answer'] = ''.join([i for i in response.css("div.mdPstdBA div.ptsQes p.queTxt::text").extract()])
    item['best_answer_link'] = ''.join(response.css("div.mdPstdBA p:not([class]) a::text").extract())

    yield item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `item` property returns as a list, which is why they look comma-separated in your file. However, the last four item properties you're dealing with won't be lists, because you're using `''.join()` on them. And if you want each list item to populate its own cell in a csv file in Excel, you'll need to iterate through your lists and `yield` each one separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yet, I am not sure how to amend it. Do you mean to just add yield[‘xxx’] one by one will solve that issues?

Comment: If you want each item in its own row in a spreadsheet, you can `yield` each element individually in a `for` loop, iterating through the lists of parameters you've collected.